# Data Warehouse Query to find gap in dates

Tags: t-sql, data-warehouse

I have the following result set

```
+----+----------------+--------------+----------------+-------------------+----------------+------------+-------------+------------+
| ID | row_start_date | row_end_date | terminate_date | termDateWasMember | dropped_reason | join_date  | rejoin_date | renew_date |
+----+----------------+--------------+----------------+-------------------+----------------+------------+-------------+------------+
| 1  | 12-31-2016     | 02-03-2017   | NULL           | Member            | NULL           | 08-08-2016 | NULL        | 08-08-2016 |
+----+----------------+--------------+----------------+-------------------+----------------+------------+-------------+------------+
| 1  | 2-4-2016       | 2-14-2017    | NULL           | Member            | NULL           | 08-08-2016 | NULL        | 08-08-2016 |
+----+----------------+--------------+----------------+-------------------+----------------+------------+-------------+------------+
| 1  | 2-15-2017      | 2-21-2017    | 2-15-2016      | NonMember         | DuesPayment    | 08-08-2016 | NULL        | 08-08-2016 |
+----+----------------+--------------+----------------+-------------------+----------------+------------+-------------+------------+
| 1  | 2-22-2017      | 12-31-9999   | NULL           | Member            | DuesPayment    | 08-08-2016 | 2-22-2016   | 08-08-2016 |
+----+----------------+--------------+----------------+-------------------+----------------+------------+-------------+------------+
```

What i'm trying to accomplish is to create a report or something that will show that the person (in this case it's one person, in the DW many) on one line that they were a member up to (terminate date) then post terminate date did they join again.  So if Bob was a member from 08-08-2016 and terminated membership on 02-15-2017 and then paid dues and rejoined on 02-22-2017  I want to show bob was a member from 8-8-2016 terminated on  and Rejoined on .

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to do this.  I would like to try to do this in code.
Delivery vehicle could be PowerBI, Excel 2016, Tableau SSRS

Here is the existing code i'm using

```
        SELECT  m.id AS ID ,
        CONVERT(CHAR(10),m.row_start_date,110) AS row_start_date ,
        CONVERT(CHAR(10),m.row_end_date ,110) AS row_end_date,
        CONVERT(CHAR(10),m.terminate_date,110) AS terminate_date ,
        CASE WHEN m.terminate_date IS NULL THEN 'Member' ELSE 'Non-Member' END AS termDateWasMember,
        m.dropped_reason ,
        CONVERT(CHAR(10),join_date,110) AS join_date ,
        CONVERT(CHAR(10),rejoin_date,110) AS rejoin_date ,
        CONVERT(CHAR(10),renew_date,110) AS renew_date 
        FROM    dim_membership m
        INNER JOIN dim_individual i ON m.id = i.id
        WHERE   m.source_bk IN (
        SELECT  m.source_bk
        FROM    dim_membership m
                INNER JOIN 
         ( SELECT source_bk ,MIN(terminate_date) AS terminate_date
                             FROM   dim_membership
                             GROUP BY source_bk
                             HAVING MIN(terminate_date) >= '02/15/2017'
                           ) can ON m.source_bk = can.source_bk
        WHERE   row_is_current = 'Y')
        AND m.row_start_date > '2010-12-31'
        AND m.membership_level = 'National'
        AND i.row_is_current = 'Y' 
        AND id =  9182039 --7236901   --9182039--= 9129028   
        ORDER BY m.source_bk ,
         m.row_start_date,3 DESC
```

Comment: Can you just look for NonMember rows directly followed by Member rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you can look for NonMember rows followed by Member rows, I would add a `ROW_NUMBER OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY row_start_date) AS rownum` then self join so take your query and put it inside a CTE at the top:

```
WITH (your_query) AS model
SELECT m_term.terminate_date AS gap_start
       ,m_renew.rejoin_date AS gap_end
    ,m_term.*, m_renew.*
FROM model m_term
INNER JOIN model m_renew
    ON m_renew.ID = m_term.ID
    AND m_renew.rownum = m_term.rownum + 1
    AND m_term.termDateWasMember = 'NonMember'
    AND m_renew.termDateWasMember = 'Member';
```

So it's looking for transitions from NonMember to Member and then using the date fields from the respective rows to determine the gap.

Comment: Cade, that was really close, the problem that I have is the m.term.Terminate_date is null in places except when they terminate so when it's trying to do the gap_start it's getting a null same with gap end on the rejoin_date it's null until they rejoin.  How do I handle this?

Comment: In that case, it's a little more complicated, you want to find the NonMember with a non-NULL terminate date and the first Member after it, which sounds like it won't be consecutive.  So you would need to do a kind of triangular correlated lookup to find MIN(rownum) where ID is equal and m_renew.rownum > m_term.rownum.  Or you could filter out the unnecessary rows in the first subquery describing other changes so that the transitions _look_ like they are consecutive by the time you are